# Mail Client Not Opening with mailto anchor href

Tags: javascript, html, mailto

I am trying to open the default mail client using anchor tag mailto option, The mail body text contains thai strings . Nothing happens when the mail link clicked. This is the anchor tag

```
   <a href="mailto:Test@test.com? 
   cc=TestThailandSupport@test.com&amp;subject=ชื่อลูกค้า- 
   VHO_Thailand_00405_2019-04-09&amp;body=การส่งมอบรถ กรุณาดาวน์โหลด รเอกสาร 
   แนบ คือ รายชื่อการสำรวจ/ตรวจสอบแบบอิเล็กโทรนิกส์ ซึ่งเป็นรายระเอียดและขั้นตอนการส่ง 
   มอบรถได้ทาง 
   อินเตอร์เน็ต URL 
   https://htasample.sample.com/SampleUploads%2fHandOverUploads%
   2f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%3f%2dVHO%5fThailand%5f00405%5f2019%2d04
   %2d09.pdf ทางเราหวังเป็นอย่างยิ่งว่าจะได้ร่วมงานและรับใช้ท่านอีกในโอกาสต่อไป" 
   class="btn btn-success btn-sm " style="background-color:lightgray;"> 
   <span style="color:black;font-size:19px;" 
   class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></a>
```

I am binding the subject and body dynamically like this

```
   var mailToLink = "mailto:" + listdata[i].CustomerEmailID + "?cc=" + 
   listdata[i].HubEmailId + "&subject=" + encodeURIComponent(mailsubject) 
   + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent(finalstring) + "";
```

This is the fiddle url https://jsfiddle.net/sagarj1987/sy7cqgva/

How can i display mail client with this data, Thanks in advance

Comment: `"<a href="` what's with the quotations? Is it a copy-paste error or is it your actual code?

Comment: You can see that his entire code block is wrapped with quotations. Not specific to the anchor tag.

Comment: @kobe I'm asking because if they're not showing the full code, this may very well be `var html = "<a href="mailto:....` and of course that wouldn't fly. Since the only error description is "nothing happens" this may very well be a syntax error OP didn't notice because they're not looking at the console.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Its just a copy-paste error

Comment: I see. But after running his code, it indeed doesn't run. I'm playing around with it now.

Comment: I copy-pasted your code into an html file (just adding some text inside the `a` before the `span` so it was easier to click. Works on my machine. It tried to open gmail (which is blocked on the network I'm on ATM, so I couldn't further test it).

Comment: @SagarJagadesh I found that the subject was too long. No issues with the text, just the length

Comment: @Kobe I tried with reducing the text length of subject , But still its the same issue , The same text when converted to english it works

Comment: @SagarJagadesh Can you paste the whole <head> of the document ?

Comment: @klugjo this the fiddle url https://jsfiddle.net/sagarj1987/sy7cqgva/

Comment: The link in your original fiddle works fine in Outlook 365, just tested it: https://imgur.com/0n9AIKG